# I am working in a javascript and I want to create two input field in s single prompt in javascript, how its possible?

Tags: javascript

I am working in a javascript and I want to create two input field in s single prompt in javascript, how its possible

```js
var rows = prompt("How many rows for your multiplication table?");

var cols = prompt("How many columns for your multiplication table?");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

A prompt contains a label, a single text field, an OK button and a Cancel button.

That's it. No API is provided to change that.

---

Consider using HTML `<input>` elements intead of a `prompt`.